# DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, kali-linux

I have been trying to automate my firefox browser in Kali linux. I installed selenium and geckdriver and running this simple script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox('/usr/bin/')
browser.get('www.duckduckgo.com')

#I saw a video where the guy mentioned that we do not have to use the path of the browser (doesn't work for me)
```

After running this simple script in python as
`python3 script.py`
the terminal freezes at:

```
script.py:4: DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
```

After Interrupting the process, it delivers the following error:

```
  browser = webdriver.Firefox('/usr/bin/')
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 4, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox('/usr/bin/')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 155, in __init__
    firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile(firefox_profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py", line 78, in __init__
    ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("parent.lock", "lock", ".parentlock"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 354, in copytree
    copy_function(srcname, dstname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 266, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 122, in copyfile
    copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 79, in copyfileobj
    buf = fsrc.read(length)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I really do not understand what does it mean. Can you please help me fix it? Thanks in advance.

PS: I also installed `geckodriver v0.26` and put in the same directory as the `script.py` file.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the expected behavior is? The deprecation warning should be just that: a warning. Likewise, the trackeback is simply a result of you interrupting the process (hence the exception name `KeyboardInterrupt`). Neither of these are unusual in and of themselves.

Comment: It doesnt show any process or progress but when I interrupt it, it displays those other details I mentioned in the problem.

Comment: What "process or progress" do you expect to see? You don't include `print` calls or other forms of IO in your script. Also, the `kali-linux` tag doesn't seem to be relevant here since your question doesn't relate to distribution-specific behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command for find the correct location of your geckdriver

```
$ Which geckdriver
```

and try this

```
path = '<your driver location>'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def setFirefoxDriver():
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

    driverPath = r'yourPathHere\geckodriver.exe'
    dService = Service(driverPath)
    d = webdriver.Firefox(service=dService)

    return d

d.get('site.com')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question asks about using a Service Object, I explicitly put the code with the Service object. The only way to explain it more clear is by adding reduntant infromation.